# Javascript function not returning properly?

Tags: javascript

```
function IsSwap()
    {
        var urlString = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/GetModelType")%>";
        var id = 
            {
                id : GetGUIDValue()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlString,
                data: id,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.toString() == 'SwapModel')
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Expected result is `true`. I can alert right before the return so I know it's getting to that point fine. In another function, I tried to get my bool and use it like this:

```
var isSwap = IsSwap();
            if (isSwap)
```

and it keeps saying `isSwap` is undefined. Why?

Comment: IS isSwap defined? Are you calling the function before it has been initialized?

Comment: at a first glance, you need to escape those double quotes in the urlString variable

Comment: the function or the variable? the function is being called fine yes. I can place an alert right before the return statement and see it popup when it needs to. Something is changing "true" to undefined on the call though when I assign it to the variable isSwap.

Comment: @Kyle -- it calls fine though. Goes through the controller, back onto the client side, and sets the return to true. For some reason the variable is being assigned true in the call to the function though.

Comment: `IsSwap` does not return a value, so the function returns `undefined`.  The `return true` is from the Ajax success callback, not `IsSwap`.

Comment: try forcing the call to be SYNCHRONOUS, not Asynchronous. You may be using the value too quickly, before the Ajax has returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using ajax requests, which are asynchronous. You can't return value from an ajax request. Try this instead:

```
function IsSwap()
    {
        var urlString = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/GetModelType")%>";
        var id = 
            {
                id : GetGUIDValue()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlString,
                data: id,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.toString() == 'SwapModel')
                    {
                        ResultIsTrue(); // call another function.
                    }
                }
            });
```

After execution, instead of using this:

```
var isSwap = IsSwap();
if (isSwap){
 // Do Somethinh
}
```

Try that:

```
IsSwap();
function ResultIsTrue(){
 // Do Same Thing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't return from an ajax call like that.

Essentially what you're doing is returning true from the inner function.

You should just call whatever code you need in the success method as that's the only time you can guarantee that the ajax call has completed.

Comment: You still couldnt return it directly, but you could create a local variable inside the IsSwap function, set that on success and then return that.

Comment: @slandau no, it won't.  `IsSwap` *does not return a value*, so you get an undefined return value by default.

Comment: You should put the required logic within the `success: function(data)` fn. If that isn't possible you could pass a calback function to `IsSwap` which gets called on success.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX request is asynchronous, meaning that `IsSwap` will return before the response to the AJAX request.

Whatever you need to do based on `isSwap`, you should do in the success handler of your AJAX request.

**UPDATE**: This last paragraph is incorrect about it working, but worth noting about synchronous not being recommended:

Alternatively, you could make the AJAX request synchronous (by adding `async:false` to the AJAX options) and keep it how you have it - however I wouldn't recommend this as your browser will 'freeze' whilst it waits for the response.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's synchronous, he's not returning a value from IsSwap.

Answer (score -2):

Check this line:

```
var urlString = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/GetModelType")%>";
```

Try using single quotes like so:

```
var urlString = '<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/GetModelType")%>';
```

Your double quotes inside double quotes is most likely your problem.

Comment: It makes the controller call absolutely fine though and gets to the last return statement.

Comment: -1 The string is fine. The problem is that an Ajax call is async so the logic needs to be in the success handler function.